# Simple pendulum from d'Alembert's principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators

I was trying to obtain the equation of motion for a simple pendulum using d'Alembert principle. It is well known that the simple pendulum satisfies the constraint $x^2+y^2=L^2$. By using trigonometry, and by looking at a diagram, it may by parametrised as $x=L\sin(\theta)$ and $y=L\cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is an angle.

Now, d'Alembert's principle reads $\sum_{k=1}^N(\mathbf{F}^{(\mathrm{Applied})}_k-m_k\mathbf{a}_k)\cdot\delta\mathbf{r}_k=0$. Calculating the acceleration by differentiating twice the position gives $\mathbf{a}=(L\ddot{\theta}\cos(\theta)-L\dot{\theta}^2\sin(\theta),-L\ddot{\theta}\sin(\theta)-L\dot{\theta}^2\cos(\theta))$. The applied force is $\mathbf{F}=-mg\mathbf{\hat{j}}$. Also the variation of $\mathbf{r}
$ is given by $\delta\mathbf{r}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial \theta}\delta\theta=(L\cos(\theta)\ \delta\theta,-L\sin(\theta)\delta \theta)$

Inserting all of this in d'Alembert principle gives, and after doing some manipulations 
$$(\mathbf{F}-m\mathbf{a})\cdot \delta\mathbf{r}=(mL^2\dot{\theta}^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)-mL^2\ddot{\theta}\cos^2(\theta)+mgL\sin(\theta)-mL^2\ddot{\theta}\sin(\theta)-mL^2\dot{\theta}^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))\delta\theta=(-mL^2\ddot{\theta}\cos^2{\theta}-m(\theta)+mgL\sin(\theta)-mL^2\ddot{\theta}\sin^2(\theta))\delta \theta=(-mL^2\ddot{\theta}+mgL\sin(\theta))\delta\theta=0$$ Since the virtual displacements $\delta \theta$ are never zero, we get

$$\ddot{\theta}(t)=\frac{g}{L}\sin(\theta(t))$$

But this equation disagrees with the well known equation of motion for the pendulum, $$\ddot{\theta}(t)=-\frac{g}{L}\sin(\theta(t)).$$ Can anyone find my mistake? Why didn't I got the correct equation of motion for the pendulum? Is there something I am not taking into consideration?

Comment: Your position vector is wrong, it should be $\overrightarrow{R}=L\begin{pmatrix}
 \sin\left( \theta \right)  \\
- \cos\left( \theta \right) 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $\delta\overrightarrow{R}=L\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos\left( \theta \right)  \\
\sin\left( \theta \right) 
\end{pmatrix}\delta \theta$

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is correct, but  with $y=L\cos\theta$ you are setting  $\theta=0$ when the pendulum is vertically *upwards*, and not hanging vertically  *down*.  If you set $y=-L\cos \theta$ then $\theta=0$ is the usual downward hanging equilibrium point. Your equation is OK if you realize that small displacement from equilibrium in your coordinates means a small displacement from $\theta=\pi$.